# 553 5.7.1 <mydomain>: Sender address rejected: not owned by user admin@mydomain.com

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, smtp

In a rails4 application, I am trying to send emails by configuring smtp settings but I am getting the following error:

> 553 5.7.1 : Sender address rejected: not owned by user
>   admin@mydomain.com

I am using the following settings:

```
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
  ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
    :address  => "smtp.mydomain.com",
    :port  => 25,
    :domain  => "mydomain.com",
    :user_name  => "admin@mydomain.com",
    :password  => "CorrectPassword",
    :authentication  => :plain,
    :enable_starttls_auto => true,
    :openssl_verify_mode => 'none'
  }

  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = {:host => "mydomain.com"}
```

The same works when I use my gmail account settings. I got my domain from bigrock.com and all MX Records are verified. I am able to send emails manually (by logging in webmail.mydomain.com). This issue has delayed the release of my site by quite a few days. Please Help!

Comment: The mail server is rejecting your email because you're trying to send from a username which differs from the username you're logging in as, e.g. you've set the From: to be `no-reply@mydomain.com`, which is obviously not the same as `admin@mydomain.com`

Comment: Oh! You are right. Thanks for the help Marc. Its now working, after I changed the "from" field's value to same as user_name.

Answer (score 15):

As @marc-b commented,

> The mail server is rejecting your email because you're trying to send from a username which differs from the username you're logging in as, e.g. you've set the From: to be `no-reply@mydomain.com`, which is obviously not the same as `admin@mydomain.com`

And the solution was:

> .. You are right. ... I changed the "from" field's value to same as user_name.

Comment: Moderator's note: I have converted these comments to an answer so that this question can be used to close duplicate questions like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54011483/how-to-fix-netsmtpfatalerror-error-in-ruby