# smtp mail settings not working in moodle 2.6

Tags: smtp, google-apps, moodle, webmail

I am using moodle2.6.2 with essential theme.
I have created the smtp settings with gmail account, it was working fine.
If i changed my webmail account ,it shows the error like this,
"Sender address rejected: not owned by user rathish@mywebdomain.com".

Anybody can help me ?

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't recommend using Gmail or Google apps for sending emails from Moodle.

Gmail has a daily limit for sending emails and it won't allow sending emails from aliases - the email account has to exist.

http://docs.moodle.org/26/en/Email_setup_gmail

Check with your web host, they will probably have smtp - but also check their email sending limits too - I've had a site suspended because because too many emails going out.

Comment: hi Russell, i have checked with moodle forum discussions. They have suggested to change the username as same as webmail's. I have changed many times and multiple types in moodle and webmail settings. It is not working. Below links i refered but i could not get success. help http://support.mailhostbox.com/email-administrators-guide/error-codes    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21816348/553-5-7-1-mydomain-sender-address-rejected-not-owned-by-user-adminmydomain